# On Windows from a PWA can we read the device RAM?

Tags: typescript, windows, progressive-web-apps

On Windows from a Progressive Web App, can we read the device RAM?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't access those system information from the browser.

You'd have to build a web app around Electron to have access to this kind of information.